# SQL INSERT INTO does not work properly (in Java)

Tags: java, sql, combobox

I have sql code in java class. The code is just like this below.

```
private void SummTEkspor(){
        try {
        bln = (String) cmbBln.getSelectedItem();
        thn = (String) cmbThn.getSelectedItem();
        String sql1 ="DELETE FROM a.dbo.t_export";
        String sql2 ="INSERT INTO a.dbo.t_export\n" +
                     "SELECT * FROM b.dbo.export b WHERE b.sk_batch IN \n" +
                     "(SELECT sk_batch from batch_hdr WHERE bln_proses="+bln+
                     "AND thn_proses="+thn; 


            Statement st = kon.conn.createStatement();
            int rs  = st.executeUpdate(sql1);
            int rsl = st.executeUpdate(sql2);


        } catch (Exception x) {
            System.out.println("FAILED");;
        }
    }
```

when i run the sql1, it works, but when sql2, it did not work properly, and just display `FAILED` . I guess the query in sql2 didn't take any value from what selected combo box. How can i solve that? Thanks for any reply

Comment: why have you put `\n` in the queries?

Comment: Don't you think those string values bln and thn will need to be quoted? also I think there isn't proper spacing in that sql2 string, can you paste here what's the value of sql2?

Comment: its displaying failed because control goes to catch block.Print the stacktrace and update your code.

Comment: Did u run & check this query any where else like SqlDeveloper tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you query is not proper :

```
INSERT INTO a.dbo.t_export\n" +
 "SELECT * FROM b.dbo.export b WHERE b.sk_batch IN \n" +
  "(SELECT sk_batch from batch_hdr WHERE bln_proses="+bln+
    "AND thn_proses="+thn;
```

When you are creating a second select sub-query, you have not closed the `)` bracket.

Try this :

```
INSERT INTO a.dbo.t_export" +
 "SELECT * FROM b.dbo.export b WHERE b.sk_batch IN " +
  "(SELECT sk_batch from batch_hdr WHERE bln_proses='"+bln+
    "' AND thn_proses='"+thn + "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You open a bracket in `(SELECT sk_batch f` and never close it.
Use `System.out.println(sql2);` in order to see how the second query looks like, it could also be that one of the parameters `thn` and `bln` are `null` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the Query, quote the string values and put proper spaces.

```
String bln="testing";
    String thn="abc";
     String sql2 ="INSERT INTO a.dbo.t_export\n" +
                 "SELECT * FROM b.dbo.export b WHERE b.sk_batch IN \n" +
                 "(SELECT sk_batch from batch_hdr WHERE bln_proses='"+bln+
                 "' AND thn_proses='"+thn+"')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
 String sql2 ="INSERT INTO a.dbo.t_export" +
 "SELECT * FROM b.dbo.export b WHERE b.sk_batch IN " +
 "(SELECT sk_batch from batch_hdr WHERE bln_proses="+bln+
 "AND thn_proses="+thn+ ")";
```

bln_proses & thn_proses these are from same table batch_hdr ???

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are som ereasons:
- closing braket in second select statement
- if bln_proses or thn_proses are strings then you have to use ' character to encompass the values

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have put `\n` in your queries which is unnecessary, then Qualifying the table `a.dbo.t_export` is not needed.

Instead of:

```
String sql2 ="INSERT INTO a.dbo.t_export\n" +
                 "SELECT * FROM b.dbo.export b WHERE b.sk_batch IN \n" +
                 "(SELECT sk_batch from batch_hdr WHERE bln_proses="+bln+
                 "AND thn_proses="+thn;
```

Try:

```
String sql2 ="INSERT INTO dbo.t_export " +
                 "SELECT * FROM b.dbo.export b WHERE b.sk_batch IN " +
                 "(SELECT sk_batch from batch_hdr WHERE bln_proses="+bln+
                 " AND thn_proses="+thn +")";
```

If your columns are of Varchar type then you have to put values inside '' (Single Quotes).

Above query will work. But I suggest you to not use this approach because there is a chance of SQL Injection. Use Precompiled statements to avoid SQL Injection.